# Json data shown in console, but not in HTML with Angular

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an Angular app consuming a Django REST API.
I want to show a list of classrooms in a table in HTML fetching Json data, but I only get the data on the console.

Here's the code.

base.html

```
<div ng-app="userListApp">
    <div ng-controller="UsersController">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Classroom</th>
                    <th>Academic year</th>
                    <th>Floor</th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="classroom in classrooms">
                  <td>{{classroom.classroom}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.school}}</td>
                  <td>{{classroom.academic_year}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var userListApp = angular.module('userListApp', ['ngResource']);

userListApp.factory('Classroom', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/classrooms/?format=json', {}, {
          query: {
              method: 'GET',
              isArray:true,
            }
        });
    });


userListApp.controller('UsersController', function($scope, Classroom) {
  Classroom.query(function(data) {
      delete data.$promise;
      delete data.$resolved;
      $scope.classrooms = data;
      console.log(data);
      }, function(error) {
          console.log(error)
      });
    });
```

This is what I get

[image]

The exact number of rows in the html and the data in the console, but no data in the HTML tables.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console further down?

Comment: No errors down there.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `$scope.classrooms` from the watch list?  What does it show you?

Comment: Uhm, how am I doing that?

Comment: Ok, got it, find out. So, well, it shows all of the data. Like, this is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/EIPArDA.png

Comment: I attempted an answer below.  It is more of a glorified comment, but I wanted to include a lot of information so that you can make some progress.

Comment: Try just doing `$scope.classrooms=Classroom.query();`. $resource will return an empty array that gets populated when request completes

Comment: Not working. I was wondering: why does the data gets printed on the console, but not on the HTML?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `$scope.classrooms` is getting set correctly?

Comment: Can you do `<pre>{{classrooms | json}}</pre>` in your HTML?  You should see an array of objects.

Comment: With that I get a template error: "Invalid filter: 'json'"

Comment: How may I check if $scope.classrooms is getting set correctly? I'm new to Angular, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Anyway, I'm using ng-inspector for Chrome, and when I click on classrooms I get all the objects, so I think it's ok.